# The Ontological Status of Chance

Tags: ontology

An occurrence such as bumping into a friend at a bus terminal bring to fore the role of Chance in the happenings of events. In this example, would Chance be exhaustively identified as the cause of the event? If so would it be, in a similar line of thought, be posited that the universe arose from an action of Chance?

Comment: Nothing in Nature is random. . .A thing appears random only through the incompleteness of our knowledge. (Spinoza, Ethics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literature on the aleatory is enormous; to begin with, I'd point you to the [SEP article on the subject](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/chance-randomness/), and, if you are interested in Continental Philosophy, Jacques Derrida's essay "My Chances / Mes Chances: A Rendezvous with Some Epicurean Stereophonies" which, beyond the Epicurean notions hinted at in the title, also addresses Mallarme's dictum *Un coup de dés jamais n’abolira le hasard.*